# jQuery UI droppable 'drop' event to wait for revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am developing some simple drag-drop interactions with jQueryUI. Under some conditions, I would like the dragged item to go back to its original place ([revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert)) and then shake. I placed the *shake* in the [drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) of the droppable object, but it doesn't seem to wait for the revert to be finished.

What's worse, sometimes it shakes *before* starting to revert to the original position, other times it shakes *after* the full revert has been done, and other times the shake gets caught up in the middle. It's not consistent.

Is there any way to execute the [drop](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event of the droppable object **after** the draggable has completed its [revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert)?

*See this **JSFiddle** for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbQUE/*

In other words, if I set up the droppable as follows:

```
this.$el.droppable({
    drop: someFunction
});
```

...the executed function is:

```
someFunction: function(ev, el){
    $(el.draggable).effect('shake');
}
```

... and the draggable object that will fall on the droppable is set up like:

```
this.$el.draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0 // or any number for that matter
});
```

How can I make sure the "someFunction" callback will be executed after the draggable is back in its original place thanks to the revert option?

**Note:** I tried looking for some sort of after revert callback or event but it doesn't exist (at least not in jQueryUI's documentation).

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for this example?

Comment: Good idea, I'll make an edit to add one now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make jsfiddle for you example, I can apply this to your code, but generally this can be accomplished in jquery using system of [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

You will have to do something like this:

javascript:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#draggable").draggable({
         revert: "valid"
     });

     $("#droppable").droppable({
         activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
         hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
         drop: function (event, ui) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#draggable").promise().done(function () {
                     $("#draggable").effect('shake', {}, 500);
                 });
             }, 100);
         }
     });
 });
```

> **Here is a solved [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bCqY/1/)**

Incase you are wondering about the setTimeout before .promise() that is to make sure the revert animation has been activated. Then promise() will wait until it is executed.

Comment: This sounds like an awesome solution... I'm trying it out in the JSFiddle

Comment: never mind.. I solved it. Adding the jsfiddle to answer now :)

Comment: Works like a charm with the setTimeout! Thanks a lot :).