# jQuery UI- Call function on move event or after revert finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jsplumb

I'm trying to work with jsPlumb and jQuery-ui draggable objects. It's working great for the most part, but I have something that doesn't seem quite right. Basically when I drag an element off the screen it reverts back to its original position. Unfortunately, when I revert an element the connecting lines stay wherever I dropped the element.

Basically this:

[image]

Becomes this:

[image]

Then when I drag the element the nodes correct themselves. I got around this by doing this little bit of code here:

```
    var outOfBounds = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            instance.repaintEverything();
        },800);
        return isOutOfBounds();
    }

    // make them draggable
    instance.draggable($(node), {revert:outOfBounds, drag:instance.repaintEverything});
```

However, that setTimeout doesn't sit well with me. It doesn't seem like the appropriate place to call such a thing, nor a proper solution to the problem. I'd like to do something after (or while) the element is being moved around but I haven't seen anything like that in the documentation or online. It doesn't seem like anyone else even wants to do this. The closest I found was [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316011/jquery-ui-droppable-drop-event-to-wait-for-revert) but I'm not using droppable and would rather not have to add more stuff than I need to my project. Unfortunately the drag option on the draggable object is only called when dragged by the user, not when it's reverting.

Comment: Huh, that seems to work. From the way the documentation read I assumed that was called when dragging finished, and wouldn't after the revert happens. You should put that in a real answer so I can except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) callback of draggable widget to trigger re-painting, since it is triggered once the revert is done.

```
instance.draggable($(node), {
 revert:isOutOfBounds,
 drag:instance.repaintEverything,
 stop:instance.repaintEverything
});
```

Comment: Yup, this is the final code: 
instance.draggable($(node), {revert:outOfBounds, drag:instance.repaintEverything, stop:instance.repaintEverything});

Comment: @S.Buda I think you can now directly call `isOutOfBounds`, rather than `outOfBounds`..? :)